# Update MS Access table from nested query

Tags: sql, ms-access, nested

My SQL is very rusty. Am trying to update a counter in a row in a table with a COUNT(*) from that same table in the form of a nested query. The SQL is below:

```
UPDATE DWInvoiceHeader AS A
SET A.InvCount = (Select Count(B.HIINV) From DWInvoiceHeader AS B 
                  WHERE (B.HIVENT = '0') 
                  Group By B.HIINV 
                  Order By B.HIINV)
WHERE (A.HIVENT = '0');
```

The rows look like:

```
HIINV1.......Seq1.....InvCount   - want InvCount to be 3
HIINV1.......Seq2.....InvCount   - want InvCount to be 3
HIINV1.......Seq3.....InvCount   - want InvCount to be 3
HIINV2.......Seq1.....InvCount   - want InvCount to be 2 
HIINV2.......Seq2.....Invcount   - want InvCount to be 2
.
.
.
HIINVn.......Seq1.....InvCount   - want InvCount to be 1
```

The SQL above gives me the message "Operation must be an updateable query".

Any ideas ?

Comment: [Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE DWInvoiceHeader AS A
SET A.InvCount = 
(
    Select Count(B.HIINV) 
        From DWInvoiceHeader AS B 
        WHERE (B.HIVENT = '0') AND (A.HIINV = B.HIINV)
        Group By B.HIINV 
)
WHERE (A.HIVENT = '0');
```

Comment: @RawleRamkeesoon, Wasn't it a nested query you have requested? dose the above solution give the desired result set? has the above solution caused an error?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Domain Function Dcount in a way similar to:

```
UPDATE test
SET InvCount = Dcount("HIVENT","test","[HIVENT]='0'")
```

If you want to use a generic approach then I would suggest to store the counts in a working table and then update your table joining the working table.

```
    Select B.HIINV,Count(B.HIINV) as InvCount 
    into WorkingTbl
    From DWInvoiceHeader AS B 
    WHERE (B.HIVENT = '0') AND (A.HIINV = B.HIINV)
    Group By B.HIINV 

   Update   DWInvoiceHeader  A 
   Inner Join WorkingTbl b 
   on a.HIINV=b.HIINV 
   Set A.InvCount=b.InvCount
```

Comment: Tried this 2-part solution involving an intermediate table and it worked fine. The DCOUNT function code gave a "Missing operator" message.

Comment: Dcount should be like this: Dcount("HIINV" ,"DWInvoiceHeader", "(B.HIVENT = '0') AND (A.HIINV = B.HIINV)")

Comment: But In general: [Office support on Dcount function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DCount-Function-F6B5D78B-AD0B-4E42-BE7A-11A64ACBF3D3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) tip: The Count function has been optimized to speed counting of records in queries. **Use the *Count* function in a query expression instead of the DCount function**, and set optional criteria to enforce any restrictions on the results. **Use the *DCount* function when you must count records in a domain from within a code module** or macro, or in a calculated control.

Comment: try the edited Dcount function again and see if it works please